# Código em c pra calcular a hipotenusa com o cosseno e o adjacente

Tags: c

Esse aí é o código que fiz pra tentar resolver a seguinte questão[image: questão 20], não tá dando certo, alguém pode me ajudar?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main() 
{
    cos(a)
    float d, hip;

    printf("qual o angulo?\n");
    scanf("%f", & a)

    printf("qual a distancia da escada até a parede?\n");
    scanf("%f", & d);

    hip = d/cos(a)

    printf("resultado:\n%f", cos(a))

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: qual o erro, postar o codigo e uma foto sem o resultado invalido que você recebeu dificulta te ajudar amigo!

Comment: Qual o significado desta linha: cos(a)? Talvez você queira dizer: float a;

Comment: "não tá dando certo " - qual o problema exatamente ? Não compila ? Se não compila qual o erro ? Se compila porque não está dando certo ?

Answer (score 2):

Este código em C pode te ajudar a calcular!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float c1, c2, hpt, seno, cosseno, tangente;

main()
{
    c1 = 1.0; // Cateto 1
    c2 = 1.0; // Cateto 2

    hpt = pow((c1*c1)+(c2*c2),0.5); //Pitágoras

    printf("Hipotenusa é: %.2f\n\n\n", hpt);

    seno = c1/hpt;
    printf("Seno = %.2f \n",c1/hpt,seno);

    cosseno = c2/hpt;
    printf("Cosseno = %.2f \n\n",c2/hpt,cosseno);

    tangente = c1/c2;
    printf("Tangente %.2f = %.2f\n\n",c1/c2,tangente);

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bem, aquele 'cos(a)' no comecinho não faz muito sentido por que a variável 'a' não foi declarada e essa conta não vai pra lugar nenhum.

Também precisa declarar a variável 'a', e faltaram alguns ponto e virgula. Fiz algumas modificações e comentei abaixo. Aliás, seria interessante tirar o acento do "até", por que vai ficar estranho na saída.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
//cos(a)  -> Esse trecho não faz sentido aqui.
float a, d, hip; //declarei a variável 'a' aqui.

printf("qual o angulo?\n");
scanf("%f", & a); //acrescentei ';'aqui

printf("qual a distancia da escada até a parede?\n"); 
scanf("%f", & d);

hip = d/cos(a); //acrescentei ';'aqui

printf("resultado:\n%f", cos(a)); //acrescentei ';'aqui

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eai brother, tranquilo?

Vendo seu código vejo que tem alguns errinhos:

- você esqueceu de declarar a variável "a".
- Em alguns lugares faltou ";".
- nos scanfs tem espaços entre o "&" e a variável.
- Seu raciocínio está certo, mas talvez o resultado do cosseno apresentado pelo c não está de acordo com o esperado no problema, pois o valor retornado do cosseno está em radianos e no caso o ideal seria trabalhar com graus, tenta colocar: `cos(a * 3.141592/180)`

Acho que é isso...